# Literal period in Python dict

Tags: python

I'm using this code:

```
import urllib2

submit = urllib.urlencode(dict(sign.username='example'))
```

But i get this error:

`SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

`sign.username` is a parameter in the URL which I am encoding, but Python won't let me use it, how can I fix this?

Comment: Why not `submit = urllib.urlencode({'sign.username':'example'})`?

Answer (score 5):

To get around your problem, use a dictionary (dict) literal with braces `{}` and single quotes around the key and value:

```
import urllib2
submit = urllib.urlencode({'sign.username':'example'})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the dict literal format - which you should probably be doing anyway.

```
urllib.urlencode({'sign.username': 'example'})
```